# Switching and Loading One Tab from Many

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How can i set the code using Javascript or JQuery to load one tab only per time, In this code all the tabs all loaded in one time and that takes too much Memory at the same time, Specially when the Story is longer than 2000 letter, So with three parts, the page would load 6000 letter at the same time, I want to only load one part, And when i switch to another Tab, the previous tab would disappear and only show the new tab with 2000 letter only.

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#part1" role="tab">Part 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part2" role="tab">Part 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part3" role="tab">Part 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="part1" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 1</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part2" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 2</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part3" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 3</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio></div>
    </div>
```

My database is

```
[ Title  --     Part1    --     Part2   --     Part3  ]
[Part 1  --  LoremIpusem -- LoremIpusem -- LoremIpusem]
[Part 2  --  LoremIpusem -- LoremIpusem -- LoremIpusem]
[Part 3  --  LoremIpusem -- LoremIpusem -- LoremIpusem]
```

Please give me just a one example about how to do it on two tabs at least, I've checked this [code](http://www.bootply.com/95542)  but i realized that If it is loaded once, It stays loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a placeholder `data-src` and when the user clicks on the tab switch the src:

`<audio id="sound1" preload="auto" data-src="http://www.jezra.net/audio/skye_boat_song.ogg"  controls></audio>`

```
$(".nav-tabs a").click( function () {
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    var $el = $(tab).find('audio');
    var src = $el.data('src');
    $el.attr('src', src);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vtu8pz6y/

If you want to dynamically play, pause, etc:

```
   $el[0].play()
   $el[0].pause()
```

[More info here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Comment: This is perfect, But if i played the audio, Then moved to another Tab, The audio will keep playing, And if i returned to the same previous tab where the Audio is playing the Audio stops, Can this be fixed? I want to make just moving the another Tab stop the previous Audio, And not returning to the Tab.